# Adding user input to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, input, while-loop

I've been attempting this for the last couple of hours and I just can't get the code right. I want to read in user input (e.g. 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'red') and spit out the colour and the count of that colour in a dictionary.

Here is my code - I know something is definitely not right with it especially in setting up the dictionary (it also has a while loop to continually ask for input until a blank is entered by the user)

INPUT: 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'red'

```
dict = {}
car_colours = input("Car: ")
frequency = 0
  while car_colours != '':
  dict['frequency'] = car_colours.count(car_colours)
  dict['colours'] = car_colours
  frequency = frequency + 1
  car_colours = input("Car: ")
print(dict)
```

I also assume I need a for loop to get the desired output below?

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Cars that are red: 2
Cars that are blue: 1
```

I'm not actually even sure I even need this code in what I have above:

```
frequency = 0
frequency = frequency + 1
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please indent the code - it's impossible to tell where the `while` lops ends now.

Comment: What do you want to store in the dict? You can only store *one* value for each *unique* key at a time.

Comment: Sorry about that @Wojciech Ptak code has been indented now.

I'd like to store 'colour' and then 'frequency' will be the value in the dictionary.
So for each colour it will count how many times it gets entered from the user (i.e. the frequency).

Comment: Look into the [Counter class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Try first running a minimal program that does not include a loop, just asks the user once, stores that colour in a dict and prints it. This might help you learn what is going on, because - frankly - the code needs to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: Yep, I'm still very much learning but you're right - this course I am doing is asking us to do things which are way above a beginner programmer. And exactly like you said, you start to get lost in your own code... very frustrating, but thanks for the advice :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are few issues in your dictionary setup as you suspected.

'dict' is a keyword in python, I suggest avoiding that as variable name. Python dictionaries are not ordered usually. Instead of having frequency and color name separately, save the color name as key and count as value.

Here is the code with the above changes :

```
d = {}
count = 0
car_colours = raw_input("Car: ")
while car_colours != '':
    if d.has_key(car_colours):
        d[car_colours] = d[car_colours] + 1
    else:
        d[car_colours] = 1
    count = count + 1
    car_colours = raw_input("Car: ")

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print 'Cars that are ' + k + ": " + str(v)
```

Here is sample test :[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Vasanth - this is looking much better! Can I ask where does the 'd.has_key' come from?

Comment: It's a way to check if the key (color name) already exists. If it is present already, increment the counter, otherwise add it to the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Vasanth, makes sense. I know it is working on your computer, but mine keeps getting an error through Spyder, but everything looks ok to me 
  File "<string>", line unknown    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Which version of python are you using? in which line do you get the error? Can you attach the backtrace?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. I don't know how to attach the backtrace... but it's most likely specific to my computer so all good Vasanth :-) Thanks again

Comment: Accept the solution. It might help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a more suitable data structure than `dict` ?

```py
from collections import defaultdict

print "Enter car colours and ^C when done..."
try:
    car_count = defaultdict(int)
    while True:
        car_colour = raw_input("Car colour: ")
        car_count[car_colour] += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
    print "Done with input, now the result"
    print

for c in car_count:
    print "Cars that are %s: %d" % (c, car_count[c])
```

Result will be:

```
$ python dd.py 
Enter car colours and ^C when done...
Car colour: red
Car colour: red
Car colour: green
Car colour: blue
Car colour: ^C
Done with input, now the result

Cars that are blue: 1
Cars that are green: 1
Cars that are red: 2
$
```

Note: Even when the `int` in `car_count = defaultdict(int)`is not formatted properly, it is a data type. The `defaultdict` extends `dict` such that each index that has not been accessed before automatically gets assigned the initial value of that type.